# Wrong Java Version on Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins

we have jenkins slaves started by ec2 plugin. We keep on seeing java version being set to 265 when a new node is started

[image]

but slaves don't even have `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.265.b01-1.amzn2.0.1.z86_64` in `/usr/lib/jvm/`

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java
java-1.8.0
java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
java-openjdk
jre
jre-1.8.0
jre-1.8.0-openjdk
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
jre-openjdk
```

I checked all the non-jre's directories, they are all 312 versions, `java -version` shows 312, master has java `1.8.66`. And I am lost how this 265 version is set when a new node is added.
there is no JVM version selected on master in any settings as far as I could tell.

help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps:

1. Check the agent Log to determine the location of `remoting` directory and `remoting.jar` in the slave server.
2. `Disconnect` agent
3. Delete both `remoting` directory and `remoting.jar`
4. `Launch` the agent.

The agent refer to the data present inside the `jarCache` directory inside `remoting`.